# CakePHP achievements and reputation system

Tags: php, cakephp

This is something that has been asked on Stack Overflow before, but I haven't seen anything related to CakePHP so I'm still fairly stumped regarding this subject area.

So I have an app that allows users, posts and comments. Users can create posts and comment on posts. Pretty simple stuff.

What I want to do is add two features (not related to each other):

- Achievements/Badges
- Reputation

The general idea is that as a user does something such as create an account, create a post 10 times, or delete posts etc.. it will add or deplete reputation. and if a certain criteria is met then create a badge or achievement.

The way I see this working, is to have an achievements table:

```
id
title
description
image
```

and a relation table

```
id
achievement_id
user_id
date
```

and then users will have a rolling integer in the users table for reputation.

The part where I am stumped is when and how to create these records when criteria is met without having to shove loads of logic inside all my methods to check various things etc.

So for example if I have a simple add post method, how would I achieve the following:

1. Add 10 points to the user reputation for each successful post
2. Add a badge for the users first post
3. Add a badge for the users 10th post

The tricky part is the 10th post achievement, as it seems I'd need someway of checking each time a post was made how many other posts that user had done and if it matched a number, but this number e.g. would need to be pulled from somewhere better than the actual code. Perhaps another table containing rules? e.g.

```
id
title
description
```

And then have a link in the achievements table like rule_id to relate it and perhaps an action count as well so it needs to run it so many times...

What would be the best way of doing this for those 3 items as an example so I can have a base for doing the other achievements and reputation in the app. Needs to be Cake specific.

Thanks

Comment: Are you familiar with Model callbacks like afterSave() etc.? that's what I would use http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html

Comment: Not familiar with them no. Would it be possible to get an example of how one might use said method in conjunction with an achievements and actions table to populate an achievements_users table if that makes sense... Seems like I need almost event listeners.

Comment: Click on the link in my comment for examples. It basically is an 'event listener'. Whenever you call `$this->Model->save()` from a controller, it will run whatever you code you put in that model's `afterSave()` function.

Comment: That's the part that is stumping me though. a.) where would I place the afterSave code. 2.) what would I put in it to say check if a certain criteria had been met, based on those table structures.

Comment: you create an afterSave() function inside your Model file.

Comment: Would that be the achievements model, action model, or the post model if for example I was checking if a person had made 10 posts. And then what would I put in the function to check if they met the action, and if so create the achievement? Thanks.

Comment: If you want to check number of POSTS you should use the POST model.

Answer (score 1):

Cameron I think you should look at the CakePhp [Events system](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/events.html) or create [observers](http://www.labelmedia.co.uk/blog/posts/php-design-patterns-observer-pattern.html) to record your achievements

Answer (score 1):

Regarding "The tricky part is the 10 post achievement":

This can be done easily using counterCache.

More details about this CakePHP feature here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#countercache-cache-your-count